# Ruby if statement with 3 options using a variable?

Tags: ruby

I have this line of code that only has 2 options. If it is Provider Payments then use the `provider_payments_work_lists_path` `else` use the `duplicate_claims_work_lists_path`. Now I want to include a potential 3rd path. if the name == "Reimbursed Claims" then path them to `reimbursed_claims_work_lists_path`. How can I do that? Currently I have:

```
url = (workList.work_list_name == "Provider Payments") ? provider_payments_work_lists_path : duplicate_claims_work_lists_path
```

Comment: Ternary assignments are meant for simple conditions as a way to improve readability and reduce code bloat. If you're comparing 3 conditions, you're better off ditching the ternary assignment to keep the readability.

Answer (score 5):

Just use a `case` statement:

```
url = case workList.work_list_name
      when 'Provider Payments'
        provider_payments_work_lists_path
      when 'Reimbursed Claims'
        reimbursed_claims_work_lists_path
      else
        duplicate_claims_work_lists_path
      end
```